# Wrongly Making an Empty Match

Tags: regex

I've got this data:

```
73636333759.90
73637286413.70
73637286413.70
```

I want to transform it to this:

```
'73636333759.90',
'73637286413.70',
'73637286413.70',
```

However, my regex is instead producing this:

```
'73636333759.90','',
'73637286413.70','',
'73637286413.70','',
```

I get the same result, whether using Visual Studio's search and replace or Rad software's regex designer. My regex for VS is:

```
match: {[0-9\.]*}  
replace string: '\1',
```

Using regex designer I tried:

```
match: (?<accountMask>[0-9.]*)  
replace string: '${accountMask}',
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using `+` rather than `*`, `*` matches 0 or more, whereas `+` matches 1 or more.

Comment: @Nachito Why not post your comment as an answer, since it does appear to be a useful answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `+` rather than `*`, `*` matches 0 or more, whereas `+` matches 1 or more. More information [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: I don't understand the implication, which is that a '*' pattern can never be used in a capture group, because empty matches will therefore always be needlessly produced in conjuction with a non-empty match.  Something doesn't add up.