# List objects 'ls()' with pattern matching is finding too many matches

Tags: regex, r

I found the work around to this issue in my script as seen below but why is it happening?

Using `ls(pattern= ...)`  with a wild card results in more results than actually match unless an additional character or space is placed between the * and the pattern sought.

I feel I am missing a fundamental pattern matching rule here. Thanks for your help.

```
b_fa=NULL
b_fb=NULL
b_fc=NULL
b_fd=NULL

ls(pattern="b_fa*")  
[1] "b_fa" "b_fb" "b_fc" "b_fd"

ls(pattern=b_fa_*)  
[1] "b_fa"
```

Whilst [Wrongly Making an Empty Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525120/wrongly-making-an-empty-match) does touch on a similar problem it does not get at the heart of the question, which is:  **Why does using the * remove the letter previous to it when finding a match?**

Comment: read the documentation of `regex` . `*` is also for 0-times the character before

Comment: @jogo: My understanding is that your described use of * is in following a regular expression (regex) in which case it means "The preceding item will be matched zero or more times."{regex documentation}.

Comment: After further reading I think I have solved the issue. Though in the regex documentation, "A ‘regular expression’ is a **pattern** that describes a **set* of strings." regular expressions can actually be any single value that is not a metacharacter such as * or +, therefore when a * is placed in front of a regular character it treats it as a regular expression and handles the single character as @jogo describes.

Comment: In actuality, by writing "b_fa*" I am matching patterns for c("b_f", "b_fa", "b_faa", "b_faaa", etc.); it is the "b_f" that is finding all my unwanted matches.

Comment: If you understand what was wrong before, you can self-answer, @DylanS. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer I think the key thing is that `*` is not a wildcard but rather a quantifier. Probably, the regex you want is `"^b_fa"` (anything that starts with those chars) -- it is not necessary that your pattern matches the string in full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short the * is treating the previous character as a regular expression and checking for any matches including 0 or more repetitions of that character, similarly to the comment by @jogo.

My confusion was caused by taking a definition and an explanation given in R help too literaly. Both can be found using `?regexp`.

```
Definition:
A ‘regular expression’ is a pattern that describes a set of strings.

Explanation:  
A regular expression may be followed by one of several repetition quantifiers:  
*  The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.
```

Though in the regex documentation, "A ‘regular expression’ is a pattern that describes a "set of strings" such as `[[:alnum:]]`, a regular expressions can actually be any single value that is not a metacharacter such as `*` or `+`, therefore when a `*` is placed in front of a regular character the character is treated as a regular expression containing a single character string and is handled as such.

As stated by @Frank: I was using `*` as a wild card, it is not.
The period `.` matches any character; it is the closest thing to a wild card.

Answer (score 0):

try `pattern="b_faa*"` or `pattern="b_fa+"` or `pattern="b_fa.*"`